# Android SDK LogCat output not logging correctly

Tags: android, eclipse, logging, logcat

I recently performed a software updated to my Samsung Galaxy 10.1 and now i'm not getting clear/useful log data in LogCat, e.g. no Level, Time, PID, Application or Tag values and I'm not getting any debug data. None of my debug code is being output.

Is anyone else getting this problem? Is there something I need to set somewhere?

Thanks

Sample output

```
?:??: W/?(?): [ 01-16 13:26:08.115   354:  394 D/STATUSBAR-StatusBarManagerService ]
?:??: W/?(?): manageDisableList what=0x0 pkg=android
?:??: W/?(?): [ 01-16 13:26:08.122   112:  310 I/AudioHardwareTinyALSA ]
?:??: W/?(?): AudioStreamOutALSA::write setDevice
?:??: W/?(?): [ 01-16 13:26:08.122   112:  310 D/AudioHardwareTinyALSA ]
?:??: W/?(?): OutALSA::setDevice: mode = 0, newDevice=0x2, currentDevice=0x2 ,force= 0
?:??: W/?(?): [ 01-16 13:26:08.122   112:  310 D/AudioHardwareTinyALSA ]
?:??: W/?(?): OutALSA::setDevice: mDevice 0x2, newDevice = 0x2
?:??: W/?(?): [ 01-16 13:26:08.122   112:  310 D/AudioHardwareTinyALSA ]
?:??: W/?(?): setOutputVolume
```

Device details
Model Number GT-P5100
Android Version 4.1.1
Kernal Version 3.0.31-691336

Eclipse
Version: 3.7.2
Build id: M20120208-0800

Android Development Toolkit
Version: 18.0.0.v201203301601-306762

Dalvik Debug Monitor Service
Version: 18.0.0.v201203301601-306762

Comment: Are you doing this through eclipse or ddms, or with logcat from the command line?  It looks like it might be a formatting change breaking some code which tries to parse the output, so the more raw an output you can view the better.

Comment: I'm doing this through eclipse, although I am getting this in DDMS aswell.

Comment: In he console window in eclipse I am also seeing the following stack trace [2013-01-16 20:35:02 - ddmlib] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine .... (cannot print full stack trace here)

Comment: The device is not outputting anything. However, the android application is running as expected, I will try reinstalling the samsung usb driver

Comment: Please try running 'adb logcat' from a command line and see if you get a clean display.  You will have to find the location of the adb executable in your sdk installation as it is probably not in the path yet.

Comment: Hi Chris, I get the expected output when running adb logcat. So probably something wrong with eclipse LogCat?

Comment: Yes, that or ddms is probably having its parsing tripped up by some detail of the formatting from the new android version.